# Is Freeletics a good way to start doing exercise?

Tags: strength, bodyweight-exercises, home-exercise

I am a 21 years old male around 180 cm and 72 kg.

I often do cardio exercise but I've never done any kind of strength related exercise. I want to start doing some and I was considering [Freeletics](https://www.freeletics.com/) as a starting point.

What attracted me about it was the possibility of doing the exercises almost anywhere (because not much space is needed) and not needing any additional equipment.

But I tried some of the workouts and, while I felt perfectly capable of doing some of them, there were others that I think that are too hard for me at this time.

I don't know if it would be good for me if I keep doing those workouts that I'm capable of completing right know and trying those that I can't once in a while or if it would be better to do something else.

So, **would Freeletics make an impact on me as a begginer or should I seek something easier at first?**

EDIT: The main problem for completing the workouts is that some of them are too "long" for me and I don't have the required endurance to complete them (**Dione** would be a good example of this, 3 rounds, 75 jumping jacks, 25 burpees, 50 straight leg lever,75 jumping jacks, 50 situps, 25 burpees each one of them) and for individual exercises the problem usually is a lack of strenght (I can't do a proper pullup)

Comment: What workouts and/or exercises did you find too hard at the moment? Was it because of mobility, strength or any other limitation?

Comment: @TobiasSjösten I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freeletics are great. I myself sadly cannot stand doing those exercises (tried, failed), some of us are just better suited to be gym-rats.

As a beginner these exercises will have a great impact on you. The main point being that you are a still a beginner and that means you need some quick and consistent results to keep you hooked on exercising.

Begginers get what we call beginner gains (oh how I wish I could go back) where increases in strength and muscle happen rapidly and noticably. This happens for about 3 months until your body starts to get used to training and stops the rapid improvement (you still improve tho, but slower). By doing freeletics you will notice an increase in you muscle mass as well as a very important increase in strength and endurance. You will see this by being able to last more and longer and by being able to perform new, harder exercises. Thats great because it will motivate you to continue further.

If you cannot perform an exercise just work towards it. There are tons of guides on the internet (for example. training for pullups) that will show you how to do exercises meant for building enough strength towards harder movements. Do those instead of the harder ones until you develop enough strength.

To sum it up: Yes keep at this, it might be harder at first (just try to do as much as you can) but the results will be well worth it.

Best of luck and keep on at it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every type of exercise is good to start with. However I don't know for sure if freeletics is free, so you could also look up calistenics workouts on youtube or the rest of the internet, there are plenty.

For gaining strength your body has to be shocked and has to addapt to that shock. The shock has to be great enough to still shock you. Freeletics is a many rep program, eventually you will be able to do 100 pushups easily so 50 pushups (E.G.) won't shock enough. At this time it will be better to just go to a gym or look up calistenics.

When training for strenght/ muscle you will have to look to train all muscles, the workout you included doesn't train your back very well (which is a large and important muscle group) You must aim to train all bodyparts for more strenght and goodlookingness.

It is good to start with a program, because consistency is key in training. And a program could help with this.